# Get rid of the line under that tab of the tab control

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, border

Using xaml ( wpf ) I'm trying to get rid of the line under the tab control as show in the "Illustration A" below so that it ends up looking like "Illustration B":

Illustration A

http://www.arulerforwindows.com/images/peskylinea.png

Illustration B

http://www.arulerforwindows.com/images/peskylineb.png

The line shows up when I define the Tab Item but appears to be attached to the Tab Control, as a result changing BorderThickness on either or both the Tab Item or Tab Control doesn't seem to yield the desired result.

I need to do this over a transparent background where a solid fill rectangle can't be used to mask the problem.

Here's the code:

```
<!--Tab Control-->
<Style  TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
     <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TabPanel Name="HeaderPanel" Grid.Row="0" Panel.ZIndex="1" Margin="0,0,0,-1" IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" Background="Transparent" />
                    <Border 
                        Name="Border" 
                        Grid.Row="1" 
                        Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" 
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource DefaultSystemBrush}" 
                        BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" 
                        Margin="0,0,0,0"
                        CornerRadius="4" 
                        KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
                        KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                        KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" >
                        <ContentPresenter 
                             Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                             Margin="4"
                             ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                    </Border>                                         
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Name="Border" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{StaticResource DefaultSystemBrush}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="6,6,0,0">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header" Margin="12,2,12,2"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Thanks in advance,

Rob

Comment: I may be missing something, but the default tabcontrol with a tabitem will NOT have that line in your illustration.  Are you talking about the tabs that aren't selected?  See http://blog.paranoidferret.com/index.php/2008/01/18/the-wpf-tab-control-inside-and-out/ the pics there don't show the line.

Comment: I had seen that too.  If you look closely the first few illustrations have no line below the selected tab, but the last few (after the tabitem was defined) have the line under them.

Comment: For now as a work around I am setting the top border of the tab control off, and adding a 1 pixel width rectangle on the betwen the right edge of the tab and the right edge of the tabcontrol container.  There must be a beter way.

Answer (score 2):

Using [ShowMeTheTemplate](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/tools/#ShowMeTheTemplate) I found out part of the style, it's on the TabItem.  There is a lot more in the default control template you may be interested in setting up if you override it.

```
<MultiTrigger>
  <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelected">
      <Condition.Value>
        <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
      </Condition.Value>
    </Condition>
    <Condition Property="TabItem.TabStripPlacement" Value="{x:Static Dock.Top}" />
  </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
  <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin">
    <Setter.Value>
      <Thickness>-2,-2,-2,-1</Thickness>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</MultiTrigger>
```

Comment: hmmm, i couldn't seem to get this to work - I fit it into the tabcontrol code but it didn't seem to do much.

Comment: There is a lot more in the TabItem's template.  Use that program I listed and see all of what you have to do to make it disappear.  This particular piece worked for a simple setup.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. Noticed that this line is drawn only for the tab with height set (it is set for only one tab and automatically all the tabs have the save height). So I've added a new `TabItem` with `width=0` and `height` specified and removed `height` from all the other tabs and that made the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

This works just fine.

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem">
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Chrome"
                        BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" 
                        BorderBrush="Black" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        Padding="2,2,2,1" Margin="1,1,1,0">
                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Chrome" Property="Margin" Value="1,1,1,-1"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Chrome" Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Just change Margin and Padding on selected Tab item.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <Style TargetType="TabControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>

                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel"
                              Grid.Row="0"
                              Panel.ZIndex="1"
                              Margin="0,0,0,-1"
                              IsItemsHost="True"
                              KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                              Background="Transparent" />

                        <Border x:Name="Border"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
                            KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                            KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2">

                            <Border.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                            </Border.Background>

                            <Border.BorderBrush>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                            </Border.BorderBrush>

                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                                          Margin="0"
                                          ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the margins and padding did not work well for me. Drawing a white (background color) border over the tab control border did the trick however:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 0 7 0">
        <Border x:Name="tabContentBorder" BorderThickness="2 2 2 0" Background="AliceBlue" BorderBrush="AliceBlue" CornerRadius="6 6 0 0">
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="Content" VerticalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header" Margin="7 3 7 3"/>
    </Border>
    <Border  x:Name="tabBottomBorder"  BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="2 0 2 -2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></Border>
</StackPanel>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter TargetName="tabContentBorder" Property="Background" Value="White" />
        <Setter TargetName="tabBottomBorder" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another very simple way is to just add one extra tab with zero width where you can set the height to what you want, or even just make it's visibility Hidden. Then you get to set the tab height without the annoying horizontal line on the tab where you set the height.

```
            <TabItem Header="" Width="0" Height="30" Visibility="Hidden" />
```