# Remove Border Bottom from focused TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, tabcontrol

After clicking on a tabitem I want to remove the border at the bottom.
Currently I have this:

[image]

Now I want to remove the marked border piece.

I searched alot and found this:

[Tab Item and Tab Control Border Style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740263/tab-item-and-tab-control-border-style)

[Get rid of the line under that tab of the tab control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400395/get-rid-of-the-line-under-that-tab-of-the-tab-control)

I tried both methods a long time.. but without success.

My Code:

```
<Style x:Key="MainMenu" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>

                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                    <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel" 
                                  Grid.Row="0" 
                                  Panel.ZIndex="1" 
                                  IsItemsHost="True" 
                                  KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" 
                                  Background="Transparent" />

                        <Border x:Name="Border"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                BorderThickness="0 1 0 0"
                                BorderBrush="Red"
                                Background="LightGray"
                                KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
                                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                                KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2">

                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                                          ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="MainMenuItem" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13px"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border 
                            Name="Border"
                            Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"
                            BorderBrush="Black" 
                            Padding="10px"
                            Margin="10 10 10 0"
                            BorderThickness="1,1,1,0">
                            
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        ContentSource="Header"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True" >
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" >
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you only want the red line across through the un-selected tabs?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the red line from the only the selected TabItem, update the Style to:

```
    <Style x:Key="MainMenuItem" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13px"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border 
                    Name="Border"
                    Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"
                    BorderBrush="Black" 
                    Padding="10px"
                    Margin="10 10 10 0"
                    BorderThickness="1,1,1,0">

                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                ContentSource="Header"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True" >
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" >
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}" />
                            <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Border" Value="10,10,10,-1" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

What I did was add a setter when the tab is selected and modified the margin for only that tab item